# Cast string as Guid using LinqPad

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

When I run following in the LinqPad

```
var ProductIds = from p in Products 
where p.Id = "F1FE990C-4525-4BFE-9E2C-A7AFFF0DDA1F"
select p;

ProductIds.Dump();
```

it gives me

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Guid'

I just don't know how to apply proper cast it to GUid I guess

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using the `Guid.Parse(string guid)` static method.

```
var ProductIds = from p in Products 
where p.Id == Guid.Parse("F1FE990C-4525-4BFE-9E2C-A7AFFF0DDA1F")
select p;

ProductIds.Dump();
```

Comment: Already tried it but that give me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'bool'" error

Comment: Make sure you have `==` between the comparison of p.Id and your `Guid.Parse()` statements, not a single `=`.

Comment: :) i must be drunk. Thanks Dude

Comment: @NathanAnderson Using LinqPad I am getting an error: `'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'`

Comment: Try using the constructor that takes a string as an argument. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You currently have an assignment, but you want to use a comparison - use `==` instead of `=` :

```
var ProductIds = from p in Products 
                 where p.Id == Guid.Parse("F1FE990C-4525-4BFE-9E2C-A7AFFF0DDA1F")
                 select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast it, you have to parse it like that:

```
where p.Id = Guid.Parse("F1FE990C-4525-4BFE-9E2C-A7AFFF0DDA1F");
```

Comment: Please see my response to @Nathan comment

Comment: So try `Guid.Parse("F1FE990C-4525-4BFE-9E2C-A7AFFF0DDA1F").CompareTo(p.Id) = 0`

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I guess I have drinking problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a variable using:

```
Guid guid = new Guid ("F1FE990C-4525-4BFE-9E2C-A7AFFF0DDA1F");
```

Then

```
var ProductIds = from p in Products
where p.Id == guid
select p;

ProductIds.Dump();
```