# linq join on guid and string column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm new to linq. I need to run a query that joins two columns (`AnonymousUser.AnonymousId` being `uniqueidentifier` and comment.UserId being `nvarchar(100)`), something like below:

```
        using (CommentEntities db = new CommentEntities())
        {
            // filteredComments is a query that is not run until the next .ToList()
            IQueryable<Comment> filteredComments = this.CommentGetList(...);
            var query = from comment in filteredComments
                         // following line is the syntax error, because columns' types don't match
                         join user in db.AnonymousUsers on comment.UserId equals user.AnonymousId into gj
                         from userNull in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new CommentWithName
                         {
                             Comment = comment,
                             UserId = comment.UserId,
                             FirstName = (userNull == null ? "" : userNull.Name),
                             LastName = "",
                             Email = (userNull == null ? "" : userNull.Email)
                         };
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

First I was happy writing the query with `.ToString()` ! As it turns out that entity framework doesn't know how to translate it to sql. The same is true for `Guid.Parse(string)`. Also `new Guid(string)` cannot be used in linq to entities (only parameterless constructors allowed)!

So after searching, I found out it's not possible doing such thing in EF 4.0! I migrated my code to a stored procedure that I'm not really happy about it.

Is it possible to tell entity framework to use a `CAST` in SQL?

Is there any solutions to this problem? Is there any way that I can bring the logic in code?

**NOTE**: I meant to do it in **one GO**. Otherwise one possible solution is to get Entities from first table, and put the Ids in a list and get entities from second table.

Comment: If `comment.UserId` is a string representation of a GUID, would it be any easier to turn that column into a unique identifier as well?  It may be a better solution than having the Entity Framework try to do this cast for you in SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always GUID. It may be a `Guid` or `int`, based on the type of user.

Comment: Did you try using [`Guid.Parse(string)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8067647/484214) instead of `new Guid(string)`?

Comment: Did you try :D ?? No success: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

call toList() before applying those methods. Like:

```
var Product = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == Guid.Parse("B4E913F9-166C-49BA-AADE-6DB889D1756F")).Single();
```

Would throw a

> c# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "System.Guid Parse" (System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

But this works:

```
var Product = db.Products.ToList().Where(p => p.ProductId == Guid.Parse("B4E913F9-166C-49BA-AADE-6DB889D1756F")).Single()
```

p.s.: I think you will lose lazyloading but you can do eagerloading with .Include before calling .ToList().

Comment: it would be a good idea to use eager loading if it's applicable to two tables without a relation.
P.S: there is no relation between the tables Comment and AnonymousUser

Comment: You will end up pulling your entire list into memory with this option. Only do this if the table of products is small.

Answer (score 0):

If your `list` is object list you could convert it to the type which has Guid as identifier, first create new anonymous type and then filter it base on `UserId`, sure `UserId` which is of type `int`, wont include in join:

```
     int output = 0;

     var secondList = list.Where(x=>!int.TryParse(x.UserID, out output))
                     .Select(x=>new {Comment = x, ID = new Guid(x.UserID))
                     .ToList();
```

Now you could run your query on db by using `secondList`.

Comment: I did not mention that `list` is of type `IQueryable<Comment>`.

Comment: So you mean it's a db item, in this case I'd offer to use stored procedures.

Comment: +1. Then you agree there's no way doing this by EF?
what about the newer versions of EF?

Comment: @Ashkan, Seems with EF 4.0 is impossible (with 99% chance), but may be is possible with EF 4.1 and I'm not good at 4.1, anyway, main problem here is bad design, if it was mine, first I'll fix bad design issues, then I'll think how to use EF, ...

Comment: bad design? How can I design a comment library that is reusable with different projects ? if I change `Comment.UserId` column type to `uniqueidentifier` it will not be usable with projects that use `int` column type as `UserId` ...

Comment: @Ashkan, may be some people are disagree to use OO in DB, but in my opinion, in your current situation, you could divide your comment class into three parts, one as parent and two child.

Comment: Don't understand why you say it's impossible. All you have to do is convert filteredComments.UserId to Guid before calling the join, right? But you do have to pull into memory.

Comment: @JoaoLeme, I mean it's impossible to do it without loading in memory, and if you see OPs other comments, seems `comment` table is too big, and in practice it's impossible to fetch it in memory.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri that's quite an interesting idea. one child having `UserId` as `int` and the other child as `uniqueidentifer`. thank you for the advice.